# Eloquent Model saved to DB with day and month inverted

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save my Laravel Eloquent model to the database.

All date properties are saved in wrong format to DB (even `created_at` and `updated_at`).
In example below, my `updated_at` has been renamed as `S_MODDATE` but it's still the "native" field.

Reading the date fields works fine.

**Example**

- My date in PHP : 2021-**12-07** (7th of December)
- When saved to database : 2012-**07-12** (12th of July)
- When read again from database : 2012-07-12

**Minimal example of my code :**

```
$currentDatetime = new \DateTime();
Log::debug($currentDatetime->format("Y-m-d h:i:s")); // Looks correct

$approRecord = T_Appro::find($approvalId);

$approRecord->DATESTATUT = $currentDatetime;

DB::enableQueryLog();
$approRecord->save();

Log::debug(DB::getQueryLog());
```

**Corresponding log**

```
[2021-12-07 13:17:25] local.DEBUG: 2021-12-07 01:17:25  
[2021-12-07 13:17:28] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'update [t_appro] set [DATESTATUT] = ?, [t_appro].[S_MODDATE] = ? where [T_APPROID] = ?',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      DateTime::__set_state(array(
         'date' => '2021-12-07 13:17:25.981319',
         'timezone_type' => 3,
         'timezone' => 'Europe/Brussels',
      )),
      1 => '2021-12-07 13:17:28.035',
      2 => 'S000000029',
    ),
    'time' => 468.81,
  ),
)
```

**Tested solutions**

- Add `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';` to my model
- Add following code to my model

```
public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.v';
}
```

- Set `app.php` timezone to `Europe/Brussels`

Comment: "All date properties are saved in wrong format" dates stored as per DB supported format like `Y-m-d H:i:s` you need to change formate for display purpuse.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Thank you for your comment. I am not sure I understand it but the issue does only appear when saving the data.
Fetching date column from the DB already works perfectly.
Saving date column into the DB cause bad formatting.

Comment: replace `$currentDatetime = new \DateTime();` with `$currentDatetime = now();`

Comment: Just tried but it makes no difference when saving to the database.
I guess it's a misconfiguration/bug in the Query Builder, formatting the date in the wrong format.